# Extract Ticket Number from a URL

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

In Amazon Redshift, we capture the Ticket Number for Survey we do in our company in one of the responses of the survey question:

Data

```
          question            response 
          Q10                 https://test-auth.xyz.com/login?next=%2FSSO%2Fredirect%3Fredirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Ft.corp.xyz.com%252FV511449992%252Foverview%26client_id%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Ft.corp.xyz.com%253A443%26scope%3Dopenid%26response_type%3Did_token%26nonce%3Dc981fb4f2ce6dc11ed6f1dd9170ccca9f433db940a62648a5a4effad23916f55%26sentry_handler_version%3Dtestgateway%26response_mode%3Dquery%26use_sentry_key%3D1%26state%3D%252FV511449992%252Foverview&noauth=1&require_digital_identity=false

          Q10                 https://t.test.xyz.com/P58752112
          Q10                 V501167359
          Q10                 [P59355408]
```

Data I need:

```
         question           response 
         Q10                V511449992
         Q10                P58752112
         Q10                V501167359
         Q10                P59355408
```

My Query

```sql
select 
    responseid,
    case WHEN len < 9 THEN SUBSTRING(response,(REGEXP_INSTR( response,'%252FV' )) + 5,10) 
         ELSE regexp_substr(Q10,'[^\[][a-zA-z0-9]*[0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*') 
         END  as Q10
FROM
(
    select 
        r1.response,
        r1.responseid,
        MAX(CASE WHEN questionid = 'Q10' 
                 THEN LEFT(regexp_substr(response,'[a-zA-z0-9]*[0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*'),10) 
                 ELSE NULL END) Q10,
        LEN(MAX(CASE WHEN questionid = 'Q10' 
                     THEN LEFT(regexp_substr(response,'[a-zA-z0-9]*[0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*'),10) 
                     ELSE NULL END))as len
    FROM Surveytable r1
    where r1.questionid = 'Q10'
      and response is not null
    group by r1.responseid, r1.response
)
```

But First records is where its failing.

Can someone please help?

Comment: What do you mean by "failing"? Have you tried debugging the Regex logic to identify the problem?

Comment: Its not working for the big URL where ticket number is surrounded by %252FV511449992% so I need to set it in the Outer query and replace the string by %252FV%.I wanted to see if their is a better way to do this?

Comment: Is there any element you can use to identify that code? For example, does it always have `Ft.corp.xyz.com%252` before the code?